# MCMC and Metropolis-Hastings problem(s)

Tags: markov-chains, monte-carlo

[image]

What does it mean for a particular state to be a "ground" state or a "stable" state? I should make clear that this is final exam review material and not homework.

Also, how does one compute a Gibbs distribution with a particular temperature parameter?

Comment: My guess would be that the ground state has the lowest energy while a stable state is one which has no neighbors with lower energy. But it will presumably depend on the definitions used in your particular course.

Comment: "Since S is finite, there will be some state, say $x^∗$, where the
energy $E_0 = E(x^*)$ is minimized. Of course, this may occur at many states —collectively they are called the ground states of the system."

As written in the textbook (written by the professor thus providing me no clarity when I don't understand the things discussed in class)

Comment: So yes, the ground state(s) are those state(s) where the energy is minimized. In this example state 3 is the only ground state.

Comment: That was the intuition I had. I was thrown off by "all the ground states", I suppose. That only leaves knowing how to solve 16 lol.

Comment: That's easy enough, the Gibbs distribution assigns probability $\frac{e^{-\beta E_i}}{\sum_j e^{-\beta E_j}}$ to each state $x_i$, where $\beta=\frac{1}{kT}$. Sometimes (often in math, rarely in physics) we just write $\frac{1}{T}$ instead. Physically this amounts to choosing units where $k$ is $1$. Given the scale of the numbers in your example, it looks like your source adopts this convention.

Comment: I'm a bit confused at exactly what that means. $\beta = .5$ because T is 2 in the example. So how exactly does that help me get a Gibbs distribution. I plug in the $E_i$ and the sum of the possible $j$ values to form a distribution?

Comment: Yes; you have a discrete set, so a distribution on that set is specified by a probability mass function, in this case $p(x_i)=\frac{e^{-\beta E_i}}{\sum_j e^{-\beta E_j}}$.

Comment: You're a man, a myth and a legend. All in one. For the summation in the denominator: do you sum all other possible values or only the neighboring values?

Comment: All of them, it is a normalization. You use neighbors when choosing a new state.